# SharePoint JSON footer - How to add multiple links below footer - I can only do one and need to show 5 more

Tags: json, links

SharePoint JSON footer - How to add multiple links below footer - I can only do one and need to show 5 more.

Current JSON:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "a",
    "txtContent": "Displayed Text",
    "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "href": "https://google.com"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by putting all links in a parent element. So something like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style":{
    "display": "flex",
    "flex-direction": "column",
    "justify-content": "flex-start",
    "align-items": "flex-start"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "txtContent": "Link 1",
      "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "href": "https://google.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "txtContent": "Link 2",
      "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "href": "https://google.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "txtContent": "Link 3",
      "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "href": "https://google.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "txtContent": "Link 4",
      "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "href": "https://google.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "txtContent": "Link 5",
      "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "href": "https://google.com"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's what it looks like in a form footer:

[image]

Comment: Hi - thank you but getting a code "please enter a valid JSON"

Comment: Any idea why code does not work? - Thank you

Comment: That's what happens when you cut and paste! Whoops! I was missing the closing curly brace for each `attributes` section. I've fixed it and also added some display logic to the parent div so that they stack nicely, but all of that can be removed without issue.